# Locked iPhone 4 — What specifically can I access?

Tags: icloud, iphone, activation-lock

I’m purchasing several iPhone 4 models for an art project. However they are being listed by the seller as “iCloud Locked.”

I only need them to power up so I can upload a single video via USB to play it on the screen. Can anyone tell me if this is possible?

I don’t need any other connectivity resources, and I have no intention to ever use the phones otherwise.

Comment: Does the seller say why they are locked?  You may want to be sure these are not stolen merchandise. The fact that they are locked could indicate that they have been lost or stolen.  Although that may not be the case, beware.

Comment: No, they don't specify and I doubt that they would give me a legitimate answer if I asked them directly because they just want to unload them. I'm hoping that since I don't need the typical access to the phones that I can bypass the lock but I'm not an iPhone user and don't totally understand the lock restriction

Answer (score 2):

The seller is most likely referring to [Activation Lock](https://support.apple.com/HT201365), which will prevent you from using the iPhones entirely unless you know the Apple ID and password of the legitimate owners.

You will not be able to copy data onto those phones, or view anything on the screen other than the Activation Lock screen:

[image: Activation Lock]

Pretty much the only use you could have for those iPhones would be for spare parts. However as @bjbk mentions, they were most likely stolen. I would advise you stay away from this merchandise.